# parent class self.__class__.__name__ prints name of child class

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have 2 classes: a and b. 'b' inherits from 'a'. How do i get class 'a' to print it's actual name? In the case below, it prints the name of the child class.

```
class a():
    def __init__(self):
        print("a -> " + self.__class__.__name__)

class b(a):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        print("b -> " + self.__class__.__name__)

bo = b()
```

prints:

```
a -> b
b -> b
```

Comment: Unlike in some languages, the Python object `bo` doesn't have an `a` part and a `b` part. `bo` is an instance of `b`, regardless of which method accesses the value of `self.__class__`.

Comment: Try `self.__class__.__bases__[0].__name__`...

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `__class__` variable (*not attribute*) available in all methods defined in a class block. So:

```
In [1]: class a():
   ...:     def __init__(self):
   ...:         print("a -> " + __class__.__name__)
   ...:
   ...: class b(a):
   ...:     def __init__(self):
   ...:         super().__init__()
   ...:         print("b -> " + __class__.__name__)
   ...:
   ...:

In [2]: b()
a -> a
b -> b
Out[2]: <__main__.b at 0x10ce853a0>
```

This is part of the Python [data model](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#creating-the-class-object) and it was added to allow the no-arg form of `super()` that became available in Python 3.

> `__class__` is an implicit closure reference created by the compiler
>   if any methods in a class body refer to either `__class__` or `super`.
>   This allows the zero argument form of `super()` to correctly identify
>   the class being defined based on lexical scoping, while the class or
>   instance that was used to make the current call is identified based on
>   the first argument passed to the method.

So note, this won't be available for dynamically added methods:

```
In [4]: a.a_method = a_method

In [5]: b().a_method()
a -> a
b -> b
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-5887c7d36b49> in <module>
----> 1 b().a_method()

<ipython-input-3-daf632bde4e5> in a_method(self)
      1 def a_method(self):
----> 2     print(__class__)
      3

NameError: name '__class__' is not defined
```

Comment: Thanks! this actually works better. I won't be using any dynamically added methods so that wouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you create `bo`, it's initialized as an object of type `b`. This means that for `bo`, the `self` variable whether it's used in the `a` class or the `b` class, will be of type `b`.

One alternative is to call `.__name__` on the **class itself** rather than on `self`:

```py
class a():
    def __init__(self):
        print("a -> " + a.__name__)

class b(a):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        print("b -> " + b.__name__)

bo = b()

>>> a -> a
>>> b -> b
```

However, at that point, you might as well hardcode the print statements.

Comment: This seems to work for my application. I can re-write class 'a' to check for __base__.__name__ and if it's equal to 'object' I use __class__.__name__. Not incredibly pretty but works.